# oracle getting count of players by their login date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a players table as player1 where in I want to get the count of people who have logged in the second consecutive day. So for my case the output will be 2 as 2 people have logged in the second consecutive day. I tried the following

```
select count(*) from (
select player_id from player1 
group by player_id 
having count(player_id)>1
order by player_id
) a
join player1 b
on a.player_id=b.player_id
and b.log_in_date in (b.log_in_date,(b.log_in_date+1))
```

But this is geting all the rows
That is 9 rows

[image]

Comment: Your sample data makes no sense. In some rows PLAYER_ID = 3 has NAME = Jake, in others the same id has NAME = John. Then, why don't you want something returned for the last two rows in the table? PLAYER_ID = 4 logged in on 11/1 and on 11/2, consecutive days. Finally, for clarification: If the same player logs in on consecutive days more than once (say, 8/20 and 8/21 and then also, the same player, 9/03 and 9/04) do you want to count each occurrence separately, or is that just a count of 1 (for "distinct player, who logged on consecutive days once or possibly more than once")?

Comment: Sorry i was experimenting that is why got into that problem. I have edited my question please help when you get a chance

Comment: I wanted the output as 2 as 2 people in the table have logged in consecutive days from the earliest date of their login ,others have logged in but not consecutive days from the earliest date of their login

Comment: ... but now (after changing your sample data) you have players who logged in on the **same** day - is that actually possible in your real-life data? And if it is, does that count as a "second login", or does it have to be on different days - the earliest day, and the following day? Note that in the original post, and the modified one, you didn't mention anywhere that the consecutive logins must include the **earliest** date.

Comment: No i intentionally logged in dups but only want to count players having earliest date +1 in the data could find a solution as below please let me know if any other way to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get answer as below:

```sql
select count(distinct dt) from (
  select player_id, min(log_in_date) + 1 dt
  from player1
  group by player_id 
  having count(player_id) > 1
) A join player1
on player1.player_id = a.player_id
where player1.log_in_date = dt
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Please let me know.

Comment: Select the code you posted. Then either press CTRL-K on your keyboard, or click the `{}` formatting button at the top. Both will cause the code to be formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12 and higher, you can do this easily with `match_recognize`:

```
select count(*)
from   player1
match_recognize(
  partition by player_id
  order     by log_in_date
  pattern   (^ first_date same_day* next_day)
  define    next_day as log_in_date = first_date.log_in_date + 1
);
```

The names in the `pattern` clause (and in `define`) are at our discretion (we create these names the same way we can give aliases to tables or to columns in a query). They are used to classify rows - either as "first_date", "same_day" (as the first date), or "next_day" (after the initial login date). The anchor `^` means that a match will start at the earliest date in each partition (this is used exactly the same as in regular expressions for strings).

`match_recognize` takes time to learn (for programmers who don't already know and use it), but it is very much worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  unfortunately I have 11g only